# UItextfield text in Custom UITableViewCell prints nil when i scroll up in SE

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, swift3

I am having a form made by using the `UITableView` . It is made by using the custom UITextField in the custom table view cell. But when i scroll up the top most cell of the UITableView cell prints nil. And when i try to print the data in the console it prints nil. MoreOver the text in the uitextfield in the custom cell also becomes nil. The code for getting the first cell of the UITableView cell is:

```
let username = self.profileManagement!.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)) as? RegistrationFieldTableViewCell!
```

But when i try to print the `username` in console using `po username` it returns nil.
Why it is happening ? Any ideas how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if this is the best possible answer to this question, but having faced similar issues in the past the solution that worked for me was.

Store the values in a dictionary as an when the value is entered in the adjoining textField of the cell. You can achieve this by storing the value in the dictionary or an array in the method textFieldDidEndEditing and then setting it to the appropriate textField each time the cell reloads.